# Is every totally ordered set in bijection with N?

Tags: well-orders

If we define a function f from N to a well ordered set E, such that 0 is mapped to the smallest element in E, and the successor (in E) of the f-image of an integer, is the f-image of the successor of said integer.

Intuitically, I'd say f is surjective, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What if $E$ is uncountable?

Comment: Yes I know that f is not surjective, but since by the axiom of choice every set is well orderable, seems rather counter intuitive.

Comment: I have certainly posted at least several answers on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it, because it's false even if $E$ is countable. Consider $E=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, with the order
$$
a\le b \qquad\text{for}\qquad 
b=\infty\text{ or }(a,b\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and }a\le b)
$$
Prove that $E$ is well-ordered by $\le$.

In this case the function you define is not surjective, because $\infty$ is not in the image of $f$, being the successor of no integer.

Comment: I see it now, that example was on point. Thanks.